# JavaScript for adding Honeypot functionality to form submission?

Tags: javascript, forms, honeypot

I am attempting to use the honeypot method of reducing spam from my contact form.

Honeypot hides a field through CSS so it cannot be seen by humans. A spambot will populate every field it finds in the code.

I need some JavaScript to check to see if this field is populated. If it IS, it directs the spambot to another page without submitting the form. If it is NOT populated, it sends the email and redirects the user to a thank you page.

I am a novice in JavaScript and have exhausted my limited knowledge attempting to make this work. Can someone assist me PLEASE?

Comment: You have to check this server-side.  Client-side JavaScript can be trivially defeated.

Comment: I am on a hosted server and have no control over server-side code.

Comment: One of the parts of [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is helping others to reproduce the problem. You say you are using a hosted server, can you provide the html for your form, or at least the wrapping `<form>` element and one input and the submit button as well as the current JavaScript for the form? We'd be able to see what the form is doing now, and could suggest ways to add the functionality you are asking for.

Comment: Your question is based on the assumption that “spam bots” would care about JavaScript – but I think that’s largely not the case. Most bots just fetch the HTML and parse it to see what the form looks like, and then they just make POST requests using the data structure they inferred from the HTML … so trying to “disturb” them using JavaScript is quite pointless. If you want to implement effective anti-spam measures, then first of all see to it that your code works in an environment that you have more control over (meaning, move to a platform where you _have_ control over server-side code).

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
if (document.getElementById('honeypot').value !== '') {
 window.open(http://www.advansysco.com/form_redirect.html
}
</script>

Comment: <form method="post" action="http://www.bluedomino.com/scripts/formemail.bml">

<div id="fullname">Full Name:&nbsp;<span id="white">*</span>&nbsp;</div>
<div id="field1">
 <input type="text" name="fullname" size="35" tabindex="1" /></div>
<div class="company_name">Company Name</div>
<div id="field2">
 <input type="text" name="companyname" size="35" tabindex="2" />
</div>
<div id="phone_number"><strong>Phone Number</strong></div>
 <div id="field3">
  <input type="text" name="telephone" size="35" tabindex="3" />
 </div>

Comment: @josh3736 Not if the web crawler isn't manually tailored to this website. It might just fill in all the inputs without thinking.

Comment: <div id="email">Email&nbsp;<span id="white">*</span>&nbsp;</div>
 <div id="field4">
  <input type="text" name="email" size="35" tabindex="4" />
  </div>
<div id="statecode">Zip Code</div>
<div id="field10">
  <input type="text" name="zip" size="25" tabindex="5" />
</div>
<div id="field5">
 <input type="text" id="honeypot" name="honeypot" size="35" tabindex="6" />
</div>

Comment: <div id="assist"><strong>Your Comments <span id="white">*</span></strong> <em>(Please include the machine type and listing number with your request)</em></div>
<div id="field8">
  <textarea name="comment" rows="4" tabindex="7" style="width: 490px"> Please Type Your Comments Here</textarea>
</div>

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="required" value="email, fullname,comment" />
 <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Information Request From Your Website?buyer" />
 <input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="http://www.advansysco.com/thank_you.htm" />
 <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="http://www.advansysco.com/ooops.htm" />

Comment: <div id="buttons">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
 <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
 <input type="hidden" name="my_email" value="bob@advansysco.com" />
</div>
</form>

Comment: David, that is what the spambot is expected to do

Comment: Sorry, Josh. This is what the spambot is suppose to do. If the field is hidden and still populated, then it had to be done by a spambot. The JavaScript will then NOT submit the form and redirect to another page.